# Weird behaviour from ListSurfacePlot3D

Tags: graphics3d, bugs, version-9, mac-os-x

Looking at Documentation for [`ListSurfacePlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListSurfacePlot3D.html), I follow the basic example presented there.

```
data = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "VertexData"];
ListSurfacePlot3D[data, MaxPlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> 30, Axes -> None,
  MeshFunctions -> (#1 - #2 + #3 &), MeshShading -> {None, Yellow}]
```

What happens is that, first of all the vertex data from Stanford Bunny is read and stored in `data`, but then running `ListSurfacePlot3D` returns no output (I was expecting a graphic object as shown in documentation). In fact after running the line with `ListSurfacePlot3D` I see that `data` is cleared from workspace (it doesn't contain any data, in fact it is not even defined anymore - changing color from black to blue).

It seems that `MeshShading` is causing this problem, so the following works:

```
data = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "VertexData"];
ListSurfacePlot3D[data, MaxPlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> 30, Axes -> None,
  MeshFunctions -> (#1 - #2 + #3 &)]
```

[image]

I face the same problem when trying other examples from documentation; ListSurfacePlot3D/Options/MeshShading

So, is this a bug or am I missing something?

I am using OS X 10.8.4 64 bit, and *Mathematica* version
9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013).

Comment: Here on OSX 10.8.4 and M9.0.1 the kernel crashes with this example from the doc. I think it is OK to tag this `bugs` even without confirmation of Wolfram. I reported it.

Comment: here's a bit of a workaround `ListSurfacePlot3D[data,MaxPlotPoints->50,Mesh->30,Axes->None,MeshFunctions->(#1-#2+#3&),MeshShading->{Opacity[0,White],Yellow} ]`

Comment: Works perfectly fine under Win 8 and MMA 9.0.1, will check later my Ubuntu version too.

Comment: Works fine in Win 8 v9.0.1

Comment: Works fine with the same OS and Mathematica 8

Comment: Works fine in v7 on Win7-64.  I'm tagging this as OS-X/V9 specific; if it affects any other versions please add the tags.

Comment: I can reproduce this on V9.0.1 Linux-64bit (Ubuntu 12.04 to be specific).

Comment: Works fine when I reduce number of MaxPlotPoints->24 for larger values it behaves as You described ( V9.0.1 Linux-64bit).